# How to use external config file from a server in WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, app-config

I have a more conceptual question concerning the config file of a WinForm app using C#. I'm currently developing an application which will be used by different user roles of different organisations on a Win 10 tablet. So we have a bunch of different parameters which differ according to the individual user group.
We would like to store a config file for the app on a ftp server to avoid that the file has to be replaced manually on the tablet if we make modifications of the app settings. The idea is to allow the download and update of this file at any time directly from the application on the tablet, such as start app -> open settings -> click button to update app settings -> restart app -> settings are up-to-date.

Now I would like to know if there is any good practice existing of how to manage an external config file, how to parse it and how to update the App.config.
I've seen that in the appSettings of App.config it is possible to set an external file as a config source and I had the idea to parse my config file on the server and to write its content into this external file. But I'm not sure if this is the most optimal solution.

I would be happy to maybe have other ideas about this topic.

Thank you in advance and have a nice day!

Comment: App.config is an XML file.  Parsing and modifying XML files is a solved problem.

Comment: You could also just use the appConfig to point to the FTP server and download your own XML file and not have to worry about modifying it.

Comment: You can use a HTTPS API that sends back a JSON configuration, it doesn't need to be a Settings file. You could setup `App.config` (if you still use it) to handle the case when the API doesn't respond (no connection for some reason) to define, e.g., a *default behavior*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interesting input, it helped me a lot! :)